# Hot Reloads 0 libraries out of x libraries even though there are changes to reload

Tags: flutter

When I hot reload my flutter application, it always reloads 0 out of n number of libraries (Even if I make changes).

I am using Flutter on Intellij. Everything was working fine and now it doesn't work anymore.

Flutter Doctor

> [√] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.17.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version
>   10.0.18362.720], locale en-US)
>       • Flutter version 1.17.0 at C:\Users\msoha\Desktop\Flutter\flutter
>       • Framework revision d3ed9ec945 (7 days ago), 2020-04-06 14:07:34 -0700
>       • Engine revision c9506cb8e9
>       • Dart version 2.8.0 (build 2.8.0-dev.18.0 eea9717938)
>
> [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
>   version 29.0.0)
>       • Android SDK at C:\Users\msoha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
>       • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.0
>       • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
>       • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
>       • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [√] Chrome - develop for the web
>       • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
>
> [√] Android Studio (version 3.4)
>       • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
>       • Flutter plugin version 36.0.1
>       • Dart plugin version 183.6270
>       • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
>
> [√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.3)
>       • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3
>       • Flutter plugin version 44.0.3
>       • Dart plugin version 193.6911.31
>
> [√] VS Code (version 1.38.1)
>       • VS Code at C:\Users\msoha\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
>       • Flutter extension version 3.4.1
>
> [√] Connected device (3 available)
>       • SM S367VL  • 5200e8cccc8f76a3 • android-arm    • Android 9 (API 28)
>       • Chrome     • chrome           • web-javascript • Google Chrome 80.0.3987.163
>       • Web Server • web-server       • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
>
> • No issues found! Process finished with exit code 0

For reference, I am building on an android phone.